# How to increase payment process speed of crypto currency?

Tags: cryptography

I want to make own coin. I have marketing cooperation team. I am main developer.

[Questions]

1 Making coin with pow and qr-code transaction function is possible for one man developer? Me, know C# well, but not yet C++

2 And currently bitcoin's transaction processing speed is 7 per 1 second, right?
How to increase this? How can it achieved? Is it at least possible?

Or it is impossible because crypto itself is decentralized? And what is maximum transaction processing speed can be achieved currently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is much too broad, its impossible to say whether you will be capable of creating a coin with your level of programming skill but its unlikely you will be able to if you are asking these questions, which shows a lack of core understanding about how bitcoin & other cryptocurrencies work. Bitcoin is coded in C++ and its testing framework is coded in Python so C# is not directly applicable to that code, but there may be other coins you could fork from and modify, or you could learn C++. But indeed, if you don't understand why the current transaction limit is in place or have not seen any of the research into more efficient transactions then you won't have the required knowledge to make meaningful improvements to how it works sorry

I'd suggest doing a lot more reading of firstly how bitcoin works at a fundamental level including raw transactions, block construction, etc., and then into research of scaling improvements that are being worked on such as lightning, MAST, how segwit works, etc. Note that if you want to help contribute to scaling research in bitcoin, that's a much larger and more useful area than trying to create an independent currency IMO :)

Comment: Thanks for comment. But my team want money... and me too. So we plan to do ICO within 2~3 months.  Of course I read some books about how bitcoin works.  And I will start by just copy & paste bitcoin's source itself.  From there, just I want to change some parameters like total coin numbers from 21 million (bitcoin's) to like 2 billion.  And just want to increase transaction speed per second. Is this hard to do? How to program it for fast transaction?

Comment: @leegod creating an ICO for a copy+paste coin is basically asking us how to make a scam. Don't do that, go and earn some money in legitimate ways not with an ICO

Comment: Why that is scam? Bitcoin is legitimate system, proven, there is no creator or any other hidden man can make coin. Just when it started, creator and his team get coin, it is justice because they do works.

Comment: Making an ICO for a product which is just copy pasted code and pretending it is worth money makes it a scam...